# Swift regular expression - unexpected behavior with carriage return `\r`

Tags: swift, regex, carriage-return, nsregularexpression

I have a string of a public/private RSA key in Swift, from which I want to remove the comments using regular expressions. The actual key string contains special character combinations like `\r\n` for carriage return + new line. This is an example:

```
let publicKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n0123456789\r\n0123456789\r\nabcdefgh\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\n)?-* ?(BEGIN|END) ((PRIVATE RSA|PUBLIC RSA)|(RSA PRIVATE|RSA PUBLIC)|(PRIVATE|PUBLIC)) KEY ?-*(\n)?", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, publicKey.count)
print(regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: publicKey, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: ""))
```

The printed result is

```
0123456789
0123456789
abcdefgh--
```

but should be

```
0123456789
0123456789
abcdefgh
```

But when I remove the two carriage return characters, the result is as expected, without the dashes. What is going wrong here?

Comment: @Larme `\n` string pattern (a so-called regex escape sequence) matches a newline char, same as `"\n"`, a newline char matches itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is fine. The issue is that `publicKey.count` will count line endings like `\r\n` as one character.

You may fix the issue by using

```
let range = NSMakeRange(0, publicKey.utf16.count)
```

Or, simply use `.replacingOccurrences` with `.regularExpression` option:

```
let publicKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n0123456789\r\n0123456789\r\nabcdefgh\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"
let regex = "(?i)(\n)?-* ?(BEGIN|END) ((PRIVATE RSA|PUBLIC RSA)|(RSA PRIVATE|RSA PUBLIC)|(PRIVATE|PUBLIC)) KEY ?-*(\n)?"
print( publicKey.replacingOccurrences(of: regex, with: "", options: [.regularExpression]) )
// => 0123456789
//    0123456789
//    abcdefgh
```

Just in case you want to shorten the pattern, use

```
(?i)\n?-* ?(?:BEGIN|END) (?:(?:PRIVATE|PUBLIC)(?: RSA)?|RSA (?:PRIVATE|PUBLIC)) KEY ?-*\n?
```

See the [regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/kjFwA7/1)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for both solutions! And for the cleaner regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```
let publicKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n0123456789\r\n0123456789\r\nabcdefgh\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"
let result = publicKey.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s?-+[^-]+-+\\s?", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
print(result)
```

The pattern is:

- Optional whitespace `\\s?`
- One or more dashes `-+`
- One or more non-dashes `[^-]+`
- One or more dashes `-+`
- Optional whitespace `\\s?`